Storage issue, wants to change default downloading location of app center
I use Ubuntu 24.04 (former Chromebook with chrome OS) and recently my storage got quite low. so i was wondering if i could insert a USB mount it and then change the default download location of the app center from wherever it is to the new USB that i have mounted, i'm quite new to Linux and Ubuntu so i might not understand much.
Thank you for your efforts.
